# Algorithm cycle cover in directed graph

Tags: asymptotics, bipartite-graphs

**HINT: Use bipartite matching**

I have to find a cycle cover of a directed graph G or report none exists. A cycle cover - a set of disjoint cycles covering all vertices of G.

**MY idea:
a) Since G is NOT bipartite (given), we create a bipartite graph H (with two vertex sets -= Vl and VR)
**
b) then we add the edge from G to the bipartite graph H - find the matching in H corresponding to the cycle cover in G.

There's a cycle cover if and only if for each vertex v, there's only ONE edge leaving and entering v

So time taken would be O(mn)

Comment: I don't see a question here.  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question about your situation.  We're not here to do your exercises for you.